# Showing report in Report Viewer based on conditions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting, reportviewer

I am using `ASP.NET/C#`.Currently I am displaying simple `Report` following this [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/john_charles/report-wizard-in-visual-studio-2008/).

In this tutorial they just selected the fields to display and it displayed the `Reports`.

What about `Reports` based on some conditions?

How can I show reports based on conditions?

**Example:**

Show the details of Employees whose name begins with 'A'.
I hope I am able to explain my question.

Can anyone help me to do this?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: check http://www.gotreportviewer.com/ for more information about reportviewer. 
Further it is possible by programmatically binding reports and datasets to the viewer to get different reports.

Comment: @Luuk I will check that out , but any simple example link for that will be really helpful.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
ReportDataSource rds0 = new ReportDataSource("DataSetNameDefinedInReport", data);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Reportname.rdlc";
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds0);
//show report!
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

The "data" in my case is a generic List of custom objects

Comment: I am not sure I dont have any prior experience with Report viewer.How can I specify my conditions though?Thanks.

Comment: you programmatically handle conditions before opening the report. this conditions modify the data before opening.

Comment: That means data is the dataset here and I set my condition before assigning data to ReportDataSource.Is it?Thanks

Comment: the "data" is normaly a modified copy (you don't wanna loose the original dataset) of the dataset. (Not very memory economic but effective)

Comment: Am I heading in the right direction.Do you think what I am using is a good reporting tool as it lacks cross browser support and it seems tedious.What kind of reporting tool you use.Thanks.

Comment: As a junior developer (formerly system engineer) I only worked with reportviewer. Cross browsers support wasn't an issue where as I developed an Internet Explorer based application for a company. Further I only used reportviewer only within winforms applications where browser support isn't an issue. If you have advise for me using another, better product, please keep me informed;-)

Comment: I think if the company is willing to shell out money then there are lots of good paid reporting tools , I myself am looking for free versions ,no luck so far.Inbuilt reporting seems to be tedious(again my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

Reports take parameters. You can set these to filter out the data.

This set of tutorials should get you started: [Adding Parameters to reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337432%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)